# Sending images and videos to server in android

Tags: android, json, image, web-services, video

I am creating an android application for taking photos and videos. After capture images I want to send this image with date and some text to web server. In server side I am making an application with this pictures and videos. The image captured will be saved in memory card. How can I send image with text using JSON. Also I want to send Videos to the web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a Multipart post request:(This way, you dont need to create json)

```
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(serverURL);
        MultipartEntity postEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        File file = new File("Your File path on SD card");
        postEntity.addPart("fileupload", new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg"));
        postEntity.addPart("loginKey", new StringBody(""+loginKey));
        postEntity.addPart("message", new StringBody(message));
        postEntity.addPart("token", new StringBody(token));
        post.setEntity(postEntity);
        response = client.execute(post);
```

You have to add this [mime4j](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mime4j/?source=dlp) library.

Comment: Is it possible for all types of files

Comment: I have tried only video and images as of now. But I am sure that any file will work.

Answer (score 1):

try this to uplaod text ,image to server in asynctask

```
           FileBody filebodyVideo = new FileBody(new File(
                    "Sd Card VideoPath"));

            FileBody filebodyVideo1 = new FileBody(new File("Video Upload url"));

            StringBody Title= new StringBody("Put Title Here");

            StringBody description= new StringBody("Put Desc Here");




            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();

            reqEntity.addPart("image", filebodyVideo);

            multipartContent.addPart("Title", Title);

            multipartContent.addPart("Description", description);


            httppost.setEntity(multipartContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your asynctask:

```
File file = new File("Your File path on SD card");
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("YourUrl");

MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
entity.addPart("YourKey",new StringBody("Your Text"));
entity.addPart("File", new FileBody(file));
httpost.setEntity(entity);


HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
```

Comment: this is also possible library httpp://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhttpmime43jar.htm